# Mono Compiler is not working

Tags: mono

I just downloaded mono compiler from its official website. I Opened cmd and went to mono director as told in mono document review (where it says how to start a program).

```
c->program files (X86)\Mono\bin
```

I have created a file and using notepad++ editor wrote a simple hello world program then saved it as

```
Hello.cs
```

Now when i try to execute it using

```
mcs Hello.cs
```

it give error saying

```
mcs is not recognized as internal or external command
```

what should i do to execute my file?

Comment: Look inside `bin/` ; it is probably there... And it might be named `mcs`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch mcs.bat is there.. But its like cmd  screen ? is it like this ?

Comment: I know mono only on Linux, where `mcs`  is a command line compiler (like most compilers are), actually it is a shell script.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch then how does it work ? what we are told in the mono site how to build a project is something else? can u help me

Comment: You should read the [Mono documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/), starting with their [*hello world* example](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/); of course you need a good editor. Compilers are generally command line programs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what other compilers do u have in mind for c# other than mono and visual studio ? can u please find m link to download them?

Comment: BTW, why do you use *mono* on Windows? Can you use the microsoft thing? Or why don't you install Linux?

Comment: Mono (with its `mcs` *command line compiler*) is a C# compiler. Just edit some `hello.cs`  file with your favorite editor. Then run `mcs hello.cs` in a terminal. I cannot help more, I never used Windows (and I am coding since 1974). Why is using the command line so difficult to you?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i have linux ill give it a try if it worked Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing compilers with IDEs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch mcs.bat file is a command prompt when i try to open it opens and gone what should i do now?

Comment: Mono is always a command line compiler `mcs` ; The IDE is [monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) if you need one (but I prefer much more `emacs` with `make` & `git`). You need to run `mcs` in a terminal. If you don't know how to run commands (e.g. `dir` or `echo` ...)  in a terminal you need to learn that (and it is independent of mono).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "Open mono command prompt " is missing i reinstalled the software but still it does not show up.

Comment: Your issue is to understand how to start a terminal and be able to type commands (like `dir` or `cd`) inside it. That has nothing to do with Mono. It is a basic computer skill.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i can run commands I have full knowledge and got all your points what u said but now the problem is that i cant find the command prompt in the mono folder to execute file.cs

Comment: Then follow the helloworld tutorial; you first need to compile `hello.cs` into `hello.exe` using `mcs hello.cs`  then you need to run `mono hello.exe`

Comment: I downvoted your question. You should be able to read documentation before asking.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch using command prompt i went to mono folder where i saved my file.cs file and using mcs file.cs i tried to compile it it says mcs command not found now whats my fault in it ? You should not have it downvoted bro

Comment: Then edit your question and show the *exact commands* that you have typed (in which directory, i.e. `pwd` & `dir`) and the error messages that you have gotten. *Mono* is *not* a graphical user interface application (and IDEs are not compilers). You don't need to touch the mouse to compile `hello.cs`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i edited my question please re read and help me now

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch m a dumbass. im sorry it requires to open "Open command prompt" generated by mono in start menu then it works.

Comment: You might need to type `.\mcs` ; learn more about `PATH`

Answer (score 3):

Read more about [how to set `PATH` under Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) and understand more the role of the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) (see also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922003.aspx)).

You might need to type the entire path of your `mcs` batch command. So if you installed *Mono* in `C:program files\Mono\bin` you might need to type

```
 "C:\program files\Mono\bin\mcs" hello.cs
```

<sup>(To be honest, it is `program files`  with a space that need to be escaped, so I found [this](https://superuser.com/q/279008/107016))</sup>

Alternatively, use a few `cd`, `pwd`, `dir`  commands to navigate in your file tree on the command line (or start your initial terminal by clicking appropriately somewhere). When you are in `Mono`  then type

```
 bin\mcs hello.cs
```

of course the `hello.cs`  should be at the appropriate place (or you type the entire path for it, e.g. `bin\mcs c:\some\path\to\hello.cs`)

<sup>The funny thing is that **I never used Windows**, and I have to remember how I used MSDOS in the 1980s. I'm using Unix since 1984 and Linux since 1993.</sup>

Your question is completely unrelated to Mono, and is just a basic misunderstanding of how Windows (or MSDOS) command line works. `PATH` is also, and originally, used on Unix (see some of [exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) POSIX functions), who steeled it from [Multics](http://www.multicians.org).